# What is the best approach for loading data from DB by multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, jdbc, spring-batch, java.util.concurrent

I have some data in database in parent child relation, where my table is actually representing a forest of tree data structure.
[image]

And the table structure is like:

```
row1  parent: null
row2  parent:row1
row3  parent:row2
row4  parent:row1
```

Now when I am loading this data from DB to my data structure by JDBC, then what I am doing now is:

```
1. load all row where parent is null [load all the root of trees]
2. Then for each child of each root load the child in a recursive manner.
3. But here all the trees are loaded one by one.
```

What I want to do, spawn a thread for each tree, thus all the trees can be loaded concurrently. Any framework I can use with JDBC for the same, or any suggestion, help please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst this does not directly answer your exact question, I would encourage you to review your data structure. You have used the `Adjacency List Model` which, whist simple to implement initially, opens a whole ugly can of worms when it comes to querying.

There are other models to consider, such as `Nested Set Model`, for which querying of trees and sub-trees is much easier.

Both are explained well in this article: [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Although the article is RDBMS vendor specific, if could easily be adjusted to suit your system.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am checking the article provided by you.

Comment: I liked it so much, The fetch is great, The query is complex but it will reduce the complexity in my java code, although I have not check the logic to set lft and rght while inserting a data but hope that works well as defined in the article.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the hibernate framework for manipulating(create,delete,insert,update..) data in any database,It's very flexible for data manipulation

Comment: I think I am unble to describe my problem to you. I have hibernate integrated with my application, but hibernate  will only provide caching once the data is loaded, that I can achieve by jdbc also using ehcahe/ any other cache mechanism. But my question is loading data concurrently from DB where each thread is loading a Tree, and I already have hibernate / spring-data-jpa for create,delete,insert,update.